# Bootstrap cards elements alignement

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multiple cards, I receive content of each card dynamically from backend.

```
<div *ngFor="let cardData of dataArray">
 <div class="card-header">
    <div [innerHtml]="cardData.headerContent"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="card-body">
    <div [innerHtml]="cardData.bodyContent"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="card-footer">
    <div [innerHtml]="cardData.footerContent"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that content is not well aligned with adjacent card :

[image]

How can I get this result please :
[image]

Comment: Either set a `min-height` on the `header` and `footer` elements, or use JavaScript to detect the largest height and set that height for each card.

Comment: the content is dynamic, I have more thant 8 cards , headers, bodies and footers content are dynamic , I can not put a fixed min-height :(

Answer (score -1):

Add your custom CSS with classes. Just define height in % or pc so that you can have your preference on.

Comment: the content is dynamic from backend , we cant put a fixed height %